# Why do the posterior probabilities violate the axioms of probability when we apply Bayesian update without likelihood computation?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

Suppose that the unknown parameter $\Theta$ is Bernoulli and we make $n$ observations $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$, which are continuous random variables. Assuming that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are conditionally independent given $\Theta$, Bayes rule is

$$p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(\theta|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{p_\Theta(\theta)\prod_{i=1}^nf_{X_i|\Theta}(x_i|\theta)}{\sum_{\theta'=0}^1p_\Theta(\theta')\prod_{i=1}^nf_{X_i|\Theta}(x_i|\theta')}\tag1\label1$$

Assuming that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are unconditionally independent, Bayes rule is

$$p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(\theta|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{p_\Theta(\theta)\prod_{i=1}^nf_{X_i|\Theta}(x_i|\theta)}{\prod_{i=1}^nf_{X_i}(x_i)}\tag2\label2$$

Substituting $\frac{f_{X_i|\Theta}(x_i|\theta)}{f_{X_i}(x_i)}=\frac{p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)}{p_\Theta(\theta)}$, we have

$$p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(\theta|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)}{(p_\Theta(\theta))^{n-1}}\tag3\label3$$

This form is used to implement a Bayes classifier, where $\Theta$ is the target and $X_i$ are the features. The numerator terms are approximated by using the proportion of radius neighbors (i.e. points falling within a radius). For example, if 100 points fall within the radius of $X_i$ and 10 of them have $\Theta=1$, then we assign $p_{\Theta|X_i}(1|x_i)=0.1$. If there are too few or no neighbors, we assign $p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)=p_\Theta(\theta)$.

This method has a problem. If $p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)\gg p_\Theta(\theta)$ for all $i$, then $p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(1|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)>1$ and $p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(0|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)+p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(1|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\ne1$. Thus, two of the axioms of probability are violated.

Why does this method have this problem? We can remedy that by normalizing the posterior probabilities, i.e. dividing by $p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(0|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)+p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(1|x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. However, this feels like hacking. The model described performs well in practice, but I would like a more careful analysis of this approach.

Comment: Kolmogorov's 2nd axiom $P(\Omega)=1$ is unsatisfied, this is why you need a normalisation constant (marginal likelihood). This isn't hacking, it's just applying the math. You will not have a posterior _probability_ unless you normalise.

Comment: @Digio Bayes rule already has a normalization constant. If we specify a likelihood model and use $\ref1$, the output is already normalized. However, if we use $\ref3$ by directly approximating the posterior given each feature, the output may be unnormalized. How can a formula already having a normalization constant produce an unnormalized output?

Comment: I have not looked at this in detail, but I think there may be a problem with your assumption that the observations are both conditionally and unconditionally independent. If you look at some concrete situations where this occurs, you may find your problem.

Comment: OK, now I get what you mean. But isn't this how Variational Bayes and EM work? You update your posterior distribution based on the current iteration's MAP/MLE in a sequential fashion until convergence.

Comment: Are you sure that $p(\theta|X) = \frac{p(\theta|X)}{p(\theta)}$..?

Comment: @Digio Can this method be called variational Bayes? I do not know much about it but I do not think this is variational Bayes. There is no iteration in this method. Once we have estimated the numerator terms in $\ref3$, this is a one-step calculation.

Comment: @Tim Notice the power $n-1$ in $\ref3$. In the case of one observation, $p_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x)=\frac{p_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x)}{(p_\Theta(\theta))^0}$, only the proportion of radius neighbors is computed and there is no Bayesian update.

Comment: @Tim $a=\frac a{b^0}=\frac a1$

Comment: It's not variational Bayes but it reminded some aspects of it. When you use observed values instead of random variables, what was previously a joint pdf becomes a function of the parameter only (because the data is a fixed constant). To convert it back to a distribution, you need to normalise.

Comment: @Digio Now I understand what you mean. The radius neighbors is some kind of heuristic for $p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)$ so it is not exact. The model is loosely defined from the beginning, and the likelihood is not even specified. This is a hacky method anyway.

Comment: @Tim $(3)$ is derived mathematically from $(2)$ by substituting $\frac{f_{X_i|\Theta}(x_i|\theta)}{f_{X_i}(x_i)}=\frac{p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)}{p_\Theta(\theta)}$, which is Bayes rule. So it makes sense for any $n\in\mathbb N$. For example, in the case of 2 observations, $p_{\Theta|X_1,X_2}(\theta|x_1,x_2)=\frac{p_{\Theta|X_1}(\theta|x_1)p_{\Theta|X_2}(\theta|x_2)}{p_\Theta(\theta)}=\frac{p_\Theta(\theta)f_{X_1|\Theta}(x_1|\theta)f_{X_2|\Theta}(x_2|\theta)}{f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)}$, which is Bayes rule.

Comment: @Tim $\frac{p_\Theta(\theta)\prod_{i=1}^nf_{X_i|\Theta}(x_i|\theta)}{\prod_{i=1}^nf_{X_i}(x_i)}=p_\Theta(\theta)\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{f_{X_i|\Theta}(x_i|\theta)}{f_{X_i}(x_i)}=p_\Theta(\theta)\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)}{p_\Theta(\theta)}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p_{\Theta|X_i}(\theta|x_i)}{(p_\Theta(\theta))^{n-1}}$